# What to do with Swift's "try?" that cause "Result of try? is unused"?

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

I want to call some method which can `throw` something. At the same time I don't care about the exception that may be thrown, I just want to call method. However, if I try to do something like this:

```
try? managedObjectContext.save()
```

I get warning "Result of try? is unused".
What should I do in this case? Silence warning? How?

Do something like this:

```
let error: NSError = try? managedObjectContext.save()
```

? Expression becomes twice as large and I get unused constant.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As your requirement, "At the same time I don't care about the exception that may be thrown, I just want to call method", do this:

```
try! managedObjectContext.save()
```

But it will crash if an error is thrown. So, use below code snip for safe:

```
_ = try? managedObjectContext.save()
```

Comment: Because of my inattentiveness I missed such variant) You're right.

Comment: That will crash if an error is thrown. See answer to linked duplicate.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need something like this.

```
Do {
 try managedObjectContect.Save()
}
catch let error {
   print("error")
}
```